# How to find out if a break occurred at a manually inserted \discretionary?

Tags: line-breaking, conditionals, hyphenation, discretionary, branching

How to find out if a break occurred at a manually inserted `\discretionary`?

I can't do it by assignments within the arguments of `\discretionary`—assignments are finished before decision about breaking is made:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\addto[2]{%
  \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1#2}}%
}%

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\def\test{}

\discretionary{\addto\test1wa-}{ter}{\addto\test2water}

\test

\def\test{}

\null\space\hskip\dimexpr\textwidth-5mm\relax
\discretionary{\addto\test1wa-}{ter}{\addto\test2water}

\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course they are. TeX has to process the arguments to `\discretionary` in order to know what's in them and be able to apply the discretionary if required. Paragraph breaking happens at a level that's outside the reach of the user and where assignments are no longer possible. There is no macro at that level.

Answer (score 3):

`\discretionary`'s arguments all are carried out so that boxes both for the case of breaking the line and for the case of not breaking the line are available to TeX. The measurements of these boxes are needed for deciding which arrangement looks best when the paragraph is broken into lines.

If you attempt to do funny things via the arguments of `\discretionary`, then you may easily end up with an error-message about an `! Improper discretionary list.`

If you don't mind the testing-mechanism to take several compilations you can use [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref) with module **savepos** for saving coordinates and comparing before and after doing the `\discretionary`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\zsavepos{beforeA}%
\discretionary{wa-}{ter}{water}%
\zsavepos{afterA}%
\ifnum\zposy{beforeA}=\zposy{afterA}No \else A \fi break occurred.

\leavevmode\space\hskip\dimexpr\textwidth-5mm\relax
\zsavepos{beforeB}%
\discretionary{wa-}{ter}{water}%
\zsavepos{afterB}%
\ifnum\zposy{beforeB}=\zposy{afterB}No \else A \fi break occurred.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want two labels per `\discretionary` you can use [TikZ/pgf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for saving coordinates and comparing before and after doing the `\discretionary`. This also takes several LaTeX-runs to match out. (Internally TikZ/pgf also creates some sort of label—these `\pgfsyspdfmark`-thingies—via the .aux-file for each thing, e.g., `\coordinate`, which different instances of the `tikz`-environment shall remember.)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{math}%

\newlength\scratchy

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\coordinate (before) at (0,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\discretionary{wa-}{ter}{water}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\coordinate (after) at (0,0) ;
\tikzmath{coordinate \vectoritchy;
  \vectoritchy = (before)-(after); 
  \scratchy = (\vectoritchyy);
}%
\global\scratchy\scratchy
\end{tikzpicture}%
\ifdim\scratchy=0pt No \else A \fi break occurred.

\leavevmode\null\space\hskip\dimexpr\textwidth-5mm\relax
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\coordinate (before) at (0,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\discretionary{wa-}{ter}{water}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
\coordinate (after) at (0,0) ;
\tikzmath{coordinate \vectoritchy;
  \vectoritchy = (before)-(after); 
  \scratchy = (\vectoritchyy);
}%
\global\scratchy\scratchy
\end{tikzpicture}%
\ifdim\scratchy=0pt No \else A \fi break occurred.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**!!! These approaches break ligatures and kerning etc !!!**